# i am creating a chatbot in react i need some specific replies from it instead of single keyword match

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I found simple solution in stack overflow earlier. 
    I implemented it. Now my bot replies me with words matching >=3 (greater than equals 3) but if I write `"hey how are you"` it replies all the words that includes `hey`. I want only one reply `"hey I am fine"`. 
    further more I have another array; I want to use that array as synonyms. Both codes are below.

```
 handleSubmitChat = (event) => {
            //algorithm chatbot algorithm
            event.preventDefault();

            //for single string match example: user can input water an get water word related answers...
            // let matches = this.state.keywords.filter(s => s.includes(this.state.humanarea))
            // Split spaces after user sends
            let searchString = this.state.humanarea.toLowerCase()
            let searchStringSplit = searchString.split(/(\s+)/).filter(function (e) { return e.trim().length >= 3; })
            if (searchStringSplit.length >= 1) {
                this.state.matches = this.state.keywords.filter(replykey => {
                    let containsAtLeastOneWord = false;
                    // If at least a word is matched it returns the matching answers!
                    searchStringSplit.forEach(word => {
                        if (replykey.toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
                            containsAtLeastOneWord = true;
                        }
                    })
                    if (containsAtLeastOneWord) {
                        return replykey

                    }console.log(replykey)

                })
                this.setState({
                    botarea: this.state.matches
                })
                console.log(this.state.matches)

            }
        }



 constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                humanarea: '',
                matches: [''],
                keywords: [
                    'hi',
                    'hey i am fine',
                    'hey this is flower chatbot',
                    'i need water',
                    'water makes me bloom',
                    'protect me i am hurt',
                    'disable my defence so bees can come',
                    'bees can make honey all day',
                    'thanks bees for making honey ',
                    'you are awesome',
                    'only you can touch me'
                ],

                dictonary: [ //synonyms
                    {
                        greet: `//user input should first match these key words as synonyms...`
                            [
                                'greetings',
                                'hi',
                                'hey',
                                'howdy',
                                'welcome',
                                'good morning',
                                'how are you',
                                'how goes it',
                                'howdy-do',
                                'whats happening',
                                'whats up'
                            ],
`//other synonyms....`
                        group2: ['water', 'need',],
                        group3: ['bloom',],
                        group4: ['bees',],
                        group5: ['honey',]
                    }

                ]

            }
```

I expect the output to be "hey i am fine" instead of all hey related answers. 
    if my question is "hey how are you" 
    bot replies: "hey I am fine", "hey this is flower chatbot".. and it also replies you related answers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem could be that you pick one element from your array of responses that you calculate. So let's say for the above human question - `Hey how are you`, you get 4 sentences in response pick the first one.

Now to be honest it's not that straightforward to write a bot logic.

As you are using javascript, I would recommend you to take a look at this npm module called `Botkit` - https://botkit.ai/getstarted.html.

You can also make of `Brain.js`

Follow the following steps:-

1.Install Brain.js using this command - npm install brain.js.

2.Now in your logic file you will train your neural network using something like this.

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([{input: {"Hey, how are you?"}, output: { "I am fine": 1 }},
           {input: { "Hey, how are you doing?" }, output: { "Hey, I am fine": 1 }},
           {input: { "Hey, how is your day going?" }, output: { "Hey, I am doing fine, How about you?": 1 }}]);

const output = net.run({"Hey How are you?"});
```

So, in the training section, basically your are training your neural network, based on what data you input and how do you want the bot to respond. So, by giving bot a few similar input types, we can teach him how he should respond when he receives a similar type on input or question from the user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks @zenwraight for commenting. but could you be more specific about picking the first sentence ??                                                                                               About botkit i am intermediate in js and i don't want to use any API for now i want to use my dictionary array as synonyms. if there are other ways to do it, playing with arrays do share it.         Thanks again :)

Comment: @dr.kaizoku so you will need to come up with an algorithm for this then, like because you are just looking for same words in yout dictionary, you get unrelated responses as well. How are you gonna pick which one is well suited reply ?

Comment: yeah i am struggling on that (algorithm part).. on the other side i am thinking to use brain.js to train my bot, i don't know but i have to dig deep to understand how to implement brain.js in my code. but hey thanks for replying... and if you have got any suggestions or ideas please do share with me.. thanks again

Comment: Hey Sure do you need some easy example to understand brain.js ? I can edit my answer then ?

Comment: yeah sure you don't have to edit you can just write new one :) ... brain.js with react for simple ai for now. o would appricate it.

Comment: Hey, I have added the answer, have a look and let me know if it looks like a good answer that helps you or not.

Comment: thanks brother i'll write you after my bot gets trained a little... meanwhile you can also share links related brain.js in react.   thanks again

Comment: Sure @dr.kaizoku and if your works get done, don't forget to upvote and mark this as answer for future reference. All the best, keep me posted.